# Update Angular View dynamically when MongoDB collection length changes

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I was just wondering how Angular watches for database collection changes in Mongo DB. I have a variable tracking the number of items in my MongoDB collection and I would like the front end view to interpolate the number immediately whenever a new item is added to the collection from the front end. Is this possible?

Example:

```
var Item = $resource('/api/items'),
    allItems = Item.query(function(results) {
        return results;
    });

$scope.allTodos = allItems.length;
```

Front End:

```
<p ng-show="allTodos > 0">Total Items: {{allTodos}}</p>
```

Let's assume I had some way of adding items via a form on the front end, submitting them to the database. How would the {{allTodos}} number dynamically increase (++) immediately when I add a new item? In Backbone.js, I know there is are collection watch events, ie:

```
var Collection = Backbone.collection.extend({
    //code...
}),
    c1         = new Collection();

c1.bind("add", function() {
    //do something when you add it to the collection
});
```

Is this possible with Angular? I'm sure it is, so please excuse my green-ness. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$resource.query` returns an empty object immediately. So `allItems` is not what you expect to it be. Once the operation is complete `allItems` is populated with data. There is no need to return anything from the callback

One way would be to set `allTodos` inside the callback:

```
Item.query(function(results) {
        $scope.allTodos = results.length;
    });
```

Or completely eliminate extra variable `allTodos`, make items visible in template (should be part of controller's `$scope`).

```
var Item = $resource('/api/items');
$scope.allItems = Item.query();
```

And in html

```
<p ng-show="allItems.length > 0">Total Items: {{allItems.length}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill! I've fixed the code a bit. This still doesn't update the number (length) in the view when I submit a new item to the database though. I have to refresh the page for it to change. I was wondering if this number would update immediately once an item has been added, ie: the length of my collection changed, but the allItems.length property remains the same until I manually refresh the page.

Comment: Well, perhaps, you're confusing things. `Backbone.collection` you mentioned it data on client-side. And http request fetches data from server. So you have to perform you're own polling mechanism if you want client to refresh server data in "real-time". If you're looking towards real-time databases, that actively inform clients about changes, take a look at [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/)